# Monitoring a file until a string is found

Tags: bash, grep, tail, logfiles

I am using `tail -f` to monitor a log file that is being actively written to. When a certain string is written to the log file, I want to quit the monitoring, and continue with the rest of my script.

Currently I am using:

```
tail -f logfile.log | grep -m 1 "Server Started"
```

When the string is found, `grep` quits as expected, but I need to find a way to make the `tail` quit too so that the script can continue.

Comment: I wonder on what Operating System the original poster was running. On a Linux RHEL5 system, I was surprised to find that the tail command simply dies once grep command has found the match and exited.

Comment: @ZaSter: The `tail` dies only at the next line.  Try this: `date > log; tail -f log | grep -m 1 trigger` and then in another shell: `echo trigger >> log` and you will see the output `trigger` in the first shell, but no termination of the command.  Then try: `date >> log` in the second shell and the command in the first shell will terminate.  But sometimes this is too late; we want to terminate as soon as the trigger line appeared, not when the line after the trigger line is complete.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation and example, @Alfe.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/375331/166461

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here is a simple one-liner. It doesn't need bash-specific or non-POSIX tricks, or even a named pipe. All you really need is to decouple the termination of `tail` from `grep`. That way, once `grep` ends, the script can continue even if `tail` hasn't ended yet. So this simple method will get you there:

```
( tail -f -n0 logfile.log & ) | grep -q "Server Started"
```

`grep` will block until it has found the string, whereupon it will exit. By making `tail` run from it's own sub-shell, we can place it in the background so it runs independently. Meanwhile, the main shell is free to continue execution of the script as soon as `grep` exits. `tail` will linger in its sub-shell until the next line has been written to the logfile, and then exit (possibly even after the main script has terminated). The main point is that the pipeline no longer waits for `tail` to terminate, so the pipeline exits as soon as `grep` exits.

Some minor tweaks:

- The option -n0 to `tail` makes it start reading from the current last line of logfile, in case the string exists earlier in the logfile.
- You might want to give `tail` -F rather than -f. It is not POSIX, but it allows `tail` to work even if the log is rotated while waiting.
- Option -q rather than -m1 makes `grep` quit after the first occurrence, but without printing out the trigger line. Also it is POSIX, which -m1 isn't.

Comment: This approch will leave the `tail` running in the background for-ever. How would you capture the `tail` PID within the backgrounded sub-shell and expose it the the main shell?  I can only come up with the sub-optional workaround by killing all session attached `tail` processes, using `pkill -s 0 tail`.

Comment: In most use cases it shouldn't be a problem. The reason you are doing this in the first place is because you are expecting more lines to be written to the log file. `tail`will terminate as soon as it tries to write to a broken pipe. The pipe will break as soon as `grep` has completed, so once `grep`has completed, `tail` will terminate after the log file gets one more line in it.

Comment: when i used this solution I did **not** background the `tail -f`.

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith, yes, that works in most situations, but the OP problem was that grep will not complete until tail quits, and tail won't quit until another line appears in the log file _after_ grep has quit (when tail tries to feed the pipeline that was broken by grep ending). So unless you background tail, your script will not continue execution until an extra line has appeared in the log file, rather than exactly on the line that grep catches.

Comment: Re "trail won't quit until another line appears after [the required string pattern]": That is very subtly and I completely missed that. I didn't notice because the pattern I was looking for was in the middle and it all got printed out fast. (Again the behavior you describe is very subtle)

Comment: Yes, this is a rather subtle problem, and the solution does require some unpacking to fully understand. Sorry about that, it's the best I could do! :-)

Comment: Note that `tail -f` means, it will "loop forever, checking for new data at the end of the file(s). When new data appears, it will be printed." ([Source](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm))

Comment: Yes. tail -f is a basic requirement of the solution; to be able to stop at a certain printout, you need to follow the file as new lines are written to it until the line you are looking for gets printed. Without the "-f", tail would only print whatever happens to be the last part of the file at the moment of invocation and exit.

Answer (score 68):

The accepted answer isn't working for me, plus it's confusing and it changes the log file.

I'm using something like this:

```
tail -f logfile.log | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Server Started"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

If the log line matches the pattern, kill the `tail` started by this script.

Note: if you want to also view the output on the screen, either `| tee /dev/tty` or echo the line before testing in the while loop.

Comment: This works, but `pkill` is not specified by POSIX and isn't available everywhere.

Comment: You don't need a while loop. use watch with -g option and you can spare yourself the nasty pkill command.

Comment: @l1zard Can you flesh that out?  How would you watch the tail of a log file until a particular line showed up?  (Less important, but I'm also curious when watch -g was added; I have a newer Debian server with that option, and another old RHEL-based one without it).

Comment: It's not quite clear to me why tail is even needed here. As far as i understand this correct the user wants to execute a specific command when a certain keyword in a log file appears. The command given below using watch does this very task.

Comment: Not quite -- it's checking when a given string is *added* to the log file.  I use this for checking when Tomcat or JBoss is fully started up; they write "Server started" (or similar) each time that happens.

Comment: `pkill` is not specified by POSIX but it is preinstalled on CentOS, Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian, MacOS and probably many others for a good reason.

Comment: Using grep will save you some CPU. And you can still use pkill.

Comment: @Rob Whelan - Is there a way to implement a timeout with your solution? So that I will exit after a certain time. Even if the string was not found.

Comment: You can replace pkill with break `[[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Server Started"* ]] && break`

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Bash (at least, but it seems it's not defined by POSIX, so it may be missing in some shells), you can use the syntax

```
grep -m 1 "Server Started" <(tail -f logfile.log)
```

It works pretty much like the FIFO solutions already mentioned, but much simpler to write.

Comment: This works, but tail still running untill you send a `SIGTERM` (Ctrl+C, exit command, or kill it)

Comment: @mems, any additional line in the log file will do.  The `tail` will read it, try to output it and then receive a SIGPIPE which will terminate it.  So, in principle you are right; the `tail` might run indefinitely if nothing gets written to the log file ever again.  In practice this might be a very neat solution for a lot of people.

Comment: best solution so far, also the most elegant and simple one, no pipes, no complicated scripts, also it **PRODUCES** the result, the above one with grep -q is not good for me, I need also the entire line, not just to stop when substring appear... Thank You

Answer (score 20):

There are a few ways to get `tail` to exit:

#### Poor Approach:  Force `tail` to write another line

You can force `tail` to write another line of output immediately after `grep` has found a match and exited.  This will cause `tail` to get a `SIGPIPE`, causing it to exit.  One way to do this is to modify the file being monitored by `tail` after `grep` exits.

Here is some example code:

```
tail -f logfile.log | grep -m 1 "Server Started" | { cat; echo >>logfile.log; }
```

In this example, `cat` won't exit until `grep` has closed its stdout, so `tail` is not likely to be able to write to the pipe before `grep` has had a chance to close its stdin.  `cat` is used to propagate the standard output of `grep` unmodified.

This approach is relatively simple, but there are several downsides:

- If `grep` closes stdout before closing stdin, there will always be a race condition:  `grep` closes stdout, triggering `cat` to exit, triggering `echo`, triggering `tail` to output a line.  If this line is sent to `grep` before `grep` has had a chance to close stdin, `tail` won't get the `SIGPIPE` until it writes another line.
- It requires write access to the log file.
- You must be OK with modifying the log file.
- You may corrupt the log file if you happen to write at the same time as another process (the writes may be interleaved, causing a newline to appear in the middle of a log message).
- This approach is specific to `tail`—it won't work with other programs.
- The third pipeline stage makes it hard to get access to the return code of the second pipeline stage (unless you're using a POSIX extension such as `bash`'s `PIPESTATUS` array).  This is not a big deal in this case because `grep` will always return 0, but in general the middle stage might be replaced with a different command whose return code you care about (e.g., something that returns 0 when "server started" is detected, 1 when "server failed to start" is detected).

The next approaches avoid these limitations.

#### A Better Approach:  Avoid Pipelines

You can use a FIFO to avoid the pipeline altogether, allowing execution to continue once `grep` returns.  For example:

```
fifo=/tmp/tmpfifo.$$
mkfifo "${fifo}" || exit 1
tail -f logfile.log >${fifo} &
tailpid=$! # optional
grep -m 1 "Server Started" "${fifo}"
kill "${tailpid}" # optional
rm "${fifo}"
```

The lines marked with the comment `# optional` can be removed and the program will still work; `tail` will just linger until it reads another line of input or is killed by some other process.

The advantages to this approach are:

- you don't need to modify the log file
- the approach works for other utilities besides `tail`
- it does not suffer from a race condition
- you can easily get the return value of `grep` (or whatever alternative command you're using)

The downside to this approach is complexity, especially managing the FIFO:  You'll need to securely generate a temporary file name, and you'll need to ensure that the temporary FIFO is deleted even if the user hits Ctrl-C in the middle of the script.  This can be done using a trap.

#### Alternative Approach:  Send a Message to Kill `tail`

You can get the `tail` pipeline stage to exit by sending it a signal like `SIGTERM`.  The challenge is reliably knowing two things in the same place in code:  `tail`'s PID and whether `grep` has exited.

With a pipeline like `tail -f ... | grep ...`, it's easy to modify the first pipeline stage to save `tail`'s PID in a variable by backgrounding `tail` and reading `$!`.  It's also easy to modify the second pipeline stage to run `kill` when `grep` exits.  The problem is that the two stages of the pipeline run in separate "execution environments" (in the terminology of the POSIX standard) so the second pipeline stage can't read any variables set by the first pipeline stage.  Without using shell variables, either the second stage must somehow figure out `tail`'s PID so that it can kill `tail` when `grep` returns, or the first stage must somehow be notified when `grep` returns.

The second stage could use `pgrep` to get `tail`'s PID, but that would be unreliable (you might match the wrong process) and non-portable (`pgrep` is not specified by the POSIX standard).

The first stage could send the PID to the second stage via the pipe by `echo`ing the PID, but this string will get mixed with `tail`'s output.  Demultiplexing the two may require a complex escaping scheme, depending on the output of `tail`.

You can use a FIFO to have the second pipeline stage notify the first pipeline stage when `grep` exits.  Then the first stage can kill `tail`.  Here is some example code:

```
fifo=/tmp/notifyfifo.$$
mkfifo "${fifo}" || exit 1
{
    # run tail in the background so that the shell can
    # kill tail when notified that grep has exited
    tail -f logfile.log &
    # remember tail's PID
    tailpid=$!
    # wait for notification that grep has exited
    read foo <${fifo}
    # grep has exited, time to go
    kill "${tailpid}"
} | {
    grep -m 1 "Server Started"
    # notify the first pipeline stage that grep is done
    echo >${fifo}
}
# clean up
rm "${fifo}"
```

This approach has all the pros and cons of the previous approach, except it's more complicated.

#### A Warning About Buffering

POSIX allows the stdin and stdout streams to be fully buffered, which means that `tail`'s output might not be processed by `grep` for an arbitrarily long time.  There shouldn't be any problems on GNU systems:  GNU `grep` uses `read()`, which avoids all buffering, and GNU `tail -f` makes regular calls to `fflush()` when writing to stdout.  Non-GNU systems may have to do something special to disable or regularly flush buffers.

Comment: You solution (like others, I won't blame you) will miss things already written to the log file before your monitoring started.  The `tail -f` will only output the last ten lines, and then all the following.  To improve this, you can add the option `-n 10000` to the tail so the last 10000 lines are given out as well.

Comment: Another idea:  Your fifo solution can be straightened, I think, by passing the output of the `tail -f` through the fifo and grepping on it:  `mkfifo f; tail -f log > f & tailpid=$! ; grep -m 1 trigger f; kill $tailpid; rm f`.

Comment: @Alfe: I could be wrong, but I believe having `tail -f log` write to a FIFO will cause some systems (e.g., GNU/Linux) to use block-based buffering instead of line-based buffering, which means `grep` might not see the matching line when it appears in the log.  The system might provide a utility to change the buffering, such as `stdbuf` from GNU coreutils.  Such a utility would be non-portable, however.

Comment: @Alfe: Actually, it looks like POSIX doesn't say anything about buffering except when interacting with a terminal, so from a standards perspective I think your simpler solution is as good as my complex one.  I'm not 100% sure about how various implementations actually behave in each case, however.

Comment: Actually, I now go for the even simpler `grep -q -m 1 trigger <(tail -f log)` proposed elsewhere and live with the fact that the `tail` runs one line longer in the background than it needs to.

Comment: @Alfe:  The `<(foo)` process substitution is specific to Bash (and Zsh, maybe others).  It is not POSIX conformant, so it is not appropriate for use in a portable script.

Comment: @Alfe:  Also, with `<(tail -f log)` the `tail -f log` command will continue running even after `grep` exits.  That may not be a problem in this case, but it could be a problem in other cases.

Comment: As I wrote:  With this solution the `tail` runs one line longer than necessary (without halting termination of the `grep` and thus the main command) and at least in my cases this is not a problem.  I'm hard pressed to think of a scenario in which this is more than an academic issue.

Comment: **Regarding buffering and consequent delays** a quick note for those trying to use this with any command and not only `tail`: try `stdbuf -o0` and `stdbuf -i0` in the left and right side of the pipe if you are experiencing any delays. 

In my case, I was trying to monitor `docker-compose logs` and it was the output that was buffered, nothing to do with `grep`.

Answer (score 12):

Let me expand on @00prometheus answer (which is the best one).

Maybe you should use a timeout instead of waiting indefinitely.

The bash function below will block until the given search term appears or a given timeout is reached.

The exit status will be 0 if the string is found within the timeout.

```
wait_str() {
  local file="$1"; shift
  local search_term="$1"; shift
  local wait_time="${1:-5m}"; shift # 5 minutes as default timeout

  (timeout $wait_time tail -F -n0 "$file" &) | grep -q "$search_term" && return 0

  echo "Timeout of $wait_time reached. Unable to find '$search_term' in '$file'"
  return 1
}
```

Perhaps the log file doesn't exist yet just after launching your server. In that case, you should wait for it to appear before searching for the string:

```
wait_server() {
  echo "Waiting for server..."
  local server_log="$1"; shift
  local wait_time="$1"; shift

  wait_file "$server_log" 10 || { echo "Server log file missing: '$server_log'"; return 1; }

  wait_str "$server_log" "Server Started" "$wait_time"
}

wait_file() {
  local file="$1"; shift
  local wait_seconds="${1:-10}"; shift # 10 seconds as default timeout

  until test $((wait_seconds--)) -eq 0 -o -f "$file" ; do sleep 1; done

  ((++wait_seconds))
}
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
wait_server "/var/log/server.log" 5m && \
echo -e "\n-------------------------- Server READY --------------------------\n"
```

Comment: So, where is `timeout` command?

Comment: Actually, using `timeout` is the only reliable way to not hang indefinitely waiting for a server that cannot start and has already exited.

Comment: This answer is the best. Just copy the function and call it, it's very easy and reusable

Answer (score 7):

Currently, as given, all of the `tail -f` solutions here run the risk of picking up a previously logged "Server Started" line (which may or may not be a problem in your specific case, depending on the number of lines logged and log file rotation/truncation).

Rather than over-complicate things, just use a smarter `tail`, as *bmike* showed with a perl snippit. The simplest solution is this [`retail`](https://github.com/mwh/retail) which has integrated regex support with *start* and *stop* condition patterns:

```
retail -f -u "Server Started" server.log > /dev/null
```

This will follow the file like a normal `tail -f` until the first *new* instance of that string appears, then exit. (The `-u` option does not trigger on existing lines in the last 10 lines of the file when in normal "follow" mode.)

---

If you use GNU `tail` (from *coreutils*), the next simplest option is to use `--pid` and a FIFO (named pipe):

```
mkfifo ${FIFO:=serverlog.fifo.$$}
grep -q -m 1 "Server Started" ${FIFO}  &
tail -n 0 -f server.log  --pid $! >> ${FIFO}
rm ${FIFO}
```

A FIFO is used because the processes must be started separately in order to obtain and pass a PID. A FIFO still suffers from the same problem of hanging around for a timely write to cause `tail` to receive [a SIGPIPE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), use the `--pid` option so that `tail` exits when it notices that `grep` has terminated (conventionally used to monitor the *writer* process rather than the *reader*, but `tail` doesn't really care). Option `-n 0` is used with `tail` so that old lines don't trigger a match.

---

Finally, you could use a [*stateful tail*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96285/31352), this will store the current file offset so subsequent invocations only show new lines (it also handles file rotation). This example uses the old FWTK `retail`*:

```
retail "${LOGFILE:=server.log}" > /dev/null   # skip over current content
while true; do
    [ "${LOGFILE}" -nt ".${LOGFILE}.off" ] && 
       retail "${LOGFILE}" | grep -q "Server Started" && break
    sleep 2
done
```

<sub>* Note, same name, different program to the previous option.</sub>

Rather than have CPU-hogging loop, compare the timestamp of the file with the state file (`.${LOGFILE}.off`), and sleep. Use "`-T`" to specify the location of the state file if required, the above assumes the current directory. Feel free to skip that condition, or on Linux you could use the more efficient `inotifywait` instead:

```
retail "${LOGFILE:=server.log}" > /dev/null
while true; do
    inotifywait -qq "${LOGFILE}" && 
       retail "${LOGFILE}" | grep -q "Server Started" && break
done
```

Comment: Can I combine `retail` with a timeout, like: "If 120 seconds have passed and retail still has not read the line, then give an error code and exit retail" ?

Comment: @kiltek use GNU `timeout` (coreutils) to launch `retail` and just check for exit code 124 on timeout (`timeout` will kill whatever command you use it to start after the time you set)

Answer (score 6):

So after doing some testing, I found a quick 1-line way to make this work. It appears tail -f will quit when grep quits, but there's a catch. It appears to only be triggered if the file is opened and closed. I've accomplished this by appending the empty string to the file when grep finds the match.

```
tail -f logfile |grep -m 1 "Server Started" | xargs echo "" >> logfile \;
```

I'm not sure why the open/close of the file triggers tail to realize that the pipe is closed, so I wouldn't rely on this behavior. but it seems to work for now.

Reason it closes, look at the -F flag, versus the -f flag.

Comment: This works because appending to the logfile causes `tail` to output another line, but by then `grep` has exited (probably -- there's a race condition there).  If `grep` has exited by the time `tail` writes another line, `tail` will get a `SIGPIPE`.  That causes `tail` to exit right away.

Comment: Disadvantages to this approach:  (1) there's a race condition (it may not always exit immediately) (2) it requires write access to the log file (3) you must be OK with modifying the log file (4) you may corrupt the log file (5) it only works for `tail` (6) you can't easily tweak it to behave differently depending on differnt string matches ("server started" vs. "server start failed") because you can't easily get the return code of the middle stage of the pipeline.  There is an alternative approach that avoids all of these problems -- see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This will be a bit tricky since you will have to get into process control and signaling. More kludgey would be a two script solution using PID tracking. Better would be using named pipes [like this.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash)

What shell script are you using?

For a quick and dirty, one script solution - I would make a perl script using [File:Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm)

```
use File::Tail;
$file=File::Tail->new(name=>$name, maxinterval=>300, adjustafter=>7);
while (defined($line=$file->read)) {
    last if $line =~ /Server started/;
}
```

So rather than printing inside the while loop, you could filter for the string match and break out of the while loop to let your script continue.

Either of these should involve just a little learning to implement the watching flow control you are seeking.

Comment: using bash. my perl-fu is not that strong, but I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Use pipes - they love bash and bash love them. (and your backup software will respect you when it hits one of your pipes)

Comment: `maxinterval=>300` means that it will check the file every five minutes.  Since I know that my line will appear in the file momentarily, I'm using much more aggressive polling: `maxinterval=>0.2, adjustafter=>10000`

Answer (score 4):

Read them all. tldr: decouple the termination of tail from grep.

The two forms most convenient are

```
( tail -f logfile.log & ) | grep -q "Server Started"
```

and if you have bash

```
grep -m 1 "Server Started" <(tail -f logfile.log)
```

But if that tail sitting in the background bothers you, there is nicer way than a fifo or any other answer here. Requires bash.

```
coproc grep -m 1 "Server Started"
tail -F /tmp/x --pid $COPROC_PID >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Or if it isn't tail which is outputing things,

```
coproc command that outputs
grep -m 1 "Server Started" <&${COPROC[0]}
kill $COPROC_PID
```

In bash, you can also get rid of the job control output by wrapping in ():

```
(coproc command that outputs; grep -m 1 "Server Started" ${COPROC[0]}; kill $COPROC_PID)
```

Comment: Using coproc is much neater than the other PID-capturing examples here, very nice.

Answer (score 3):

The `tail` command can be backgrounded and its pid echoed to the `grep` subshell. In the `grep` subshell a trap handler on EXIT can kill the `tail` command.

```
( (sleep 1; exec tail -f logfile.log) & echo $! ; wait ) | 
     (trap 'kill "$pid"' EXIT; pid="$(head -1)"; grep -m 1 "Server Started")
```

Comment: This is a great answer, it is simple and elegant. I like it. 

I noticed the sleep 1, I guess this is to be sure that the trap etc is setup first and the pid written? When doing the sleep, we need to then do the exec, to be sure that $! matches the tail process. 

Good thing is that this can work on MacOSX. The grep -m1 does not, but using something like `sed -n '/pattern/{p;q;}'` it is the same.

I will reply with a version of this snippet as a function

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a cleaner solution than this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# file : untail.sh
# usage: untail.sh logfile.log "Server Started"
(echo $BASHPID; tail -f $1) | while read LINE ; do
    if [ -z $TPID ]; then
        TPID=$LINE # the first line is used to store the previous subshell PID
    else
        echo "$LINE"; [[ "$LINE" == *"${*:2}"* ]] && kill -3 $TPID && break
    fi
done
```

ok, maybe the name can be subject to improvements...

Advantages:

- it doesn't use any special utilities
- it doesn't write to disk
- it gracefully quits tail and closes the pipe
- it is pretty short and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much better solution that does not require you to write to the logfile, which is very dangerous or even impossible in some cases.

```
sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f /tmp/foo | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ ;}'
```

Currently it has only one side effect, the `tail` process will remain in background until the next line is written to the log.

Comment: `tail -n +0 -f` starts from the beginning of the file.  `tail -n 0 -f` starts from the end of the file.

Comment: Another side effect I get: `myscript.sh: line 14:  7845 Terminated              sh -c 'tail...`

Comment: I believe that "next list" should be "next line" in this answer.

Comment: This works, but a `tail` process remains running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

wait for file to appear

```
while [ ! -f /path/to/the.file ] 
do sleep 2; done
```

wait for string to apper in file

```
while ! grep "the line you're searching for" /path/to/the.file  
do sleep 10; done
```

https://superuser.com/a/743693/129669

Comment: This polling has two main drawbacks: 1. It wastes computation time by going through the log again and again.  Consider a `/path/to/the.file` which is 1.4GB large; then it is clear that this is a problem.  2. It waits longer than necessary when the log entry has appeared, in the worst case 10s.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessary need tail to do that. I think the **watch** command is what you're looking for.
The watch command monitors the output of a file and can be terminated with the **-g** option when the output changed.

```
watch -g grep -m 1 "Server Started" logfile.log && Yournextaction
```

Comment: Because this runs once every two seconds it doesn't immediately exit once the line appears in the log file.  Also, it doesn't work well if the log file is very large.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/375223/watch-the-output-of-a-command-until-a-particular-string-is-observed-and-then-e

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions here have several issues:

- if the logging process is already down or goes down during the loop they will run indefinitely
- editing a log that should only be viewed
- unnecessarily writing an additional file
- not allowing for additional logic

Here is what I came up with using tomcat as an example (remove the hashes if you want to see the log while its starting):

```
function startTomcat {
    loggingProcessStartCommand="${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh"
    loggingProcessOwner="root"
    loggingProcessCommandLinePattern="${JAVA_HOME}"
    logSearchString="org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup"
    logFile="${CATALINA_BASE}/log/catalina.out"

    lineNumber="$(( $(wc -l "${logFile}" | awk '{print $1}') + 1 ))"
    ${loggingProcessStartCommand}
    while [[ -z "$(sed -n "${lineNumber}p" "${logFile}" | grep "${logSearchString}")" ]]; do
        [[ -z "$(ps -ef | grep "^${loggingProcessOwner} .* ${loggingProcessCommandLinePattern}" | grep -v grep)" ]] && { echo "[ERROR] Tomcat failed to start"; return 1; }
        [[ $(wc -l "${logFile}" | awk '{print $1}') -lt ${lineNumber} ]] && continue
        #sed -n "${lineNumber}p" "${logFile}"
        let lineNumber++
    done
    #sed -n "${lineNumber}p" "${logFile}"
    echo "[INFO] Tomcat has started"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inotify (inotifywait)

You set up inotifywait for any file change, then check the file with grep, if not found just rerun inotifywait, if found exit the loop... Smth like that

Comment: This way, the _entire_ file would have to be rechecked every time something is written to it. Doesn't work well for log files.

Comment: Another way is to make two scripts:

1. tail -f logfile.log | grep -m 1 "Server Started" > /tmp/found

2. firstscript.sh& MYPID=`$!`; inotifywait -e MODIFY /tmp/found; kill -KILL -$MYPID

Comment: I'd love you to edit your answer to show capturing the PID and then using inotifywait - an elegant solution that would be easy to grasp for someone used to grep but needing a more sophisticated tool.

Comment: A PID of what you would like to capture? I can try to make it if you explain a bit more what you want

Answer (score 0):

Alex i think this one will help you lot.

```
tail -f logfile |grep -m 1 "Server Started" | xargs echo "" >> /dev/null ;
```

this command will never give an entry on the logfile but will grep silently...

Comment: This won't work -- you have to append to `logfile` otherwise it could be an arbitrarily long time before `tail` outputs another line and detects that `grep` has died (via `SIGPIPE`).

Answer (score 0):

You want to leave as soon as the line is written, but you also want to leave after a timeout:

```
if (timeout 15s tail -F -n0 "stdout.log" &) | grep -q "The string that says the startup is successful" ; then
    echo "Application started with success."
else
    echo "Startup failed."
    tail stderr.log stdout.log
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to write a line in log file after the line appeared in auth.log

got inspired by the answer above

```
tail -f logfile.log | while read LOGLINE
do
[[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Server Started"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

for me worked next

```
tail -f -n0 /var/log/auth.log | while read LOGLINE;
do [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Removed session"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail; 
echo "$(date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S") $(whoami) Screen_Locked poweroff" >> 
/var/log/lock-unlock-user.log; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### One liner

```sh
tail -f myfile.log | while read LINE; do echo $LINE; echo "$LINE" | grep -Fq 'Listening on 0.0.0.0' && pkill -P $$; done
```

### Notes

- Based on the excellent answer by Rob https://superuser.com/a/449307/33705
- Doesn't use bash only double brackets `[[]]`
- This uses `GNU grep` to do the line matching.
- I did not see any `tail` processes running after this ends, but I might have missed it, correct me if I'm wrong.

### Explanation

```
tail -f myfile.log | while read LINE;
```

will loop line by line from `myfile.log` and send it to the `while` which will store it in a variable `$LINE`.

```
echo $LINE;
```

Will print/echo the the line so that we can monitor it, I imagine this will lose any color information.

```
echo "$LINE" | grep -Fq 'Listening on 0.0.0.0' && pkill -P $$;
```

`echo` the LINE as a "string" and send the output to grep.

grep will then look for the string "Listening on 0.0.0.0" and when it matches, kill the current process.

- `$$` is a special variable that returns the current process id.
- grep `-F` means "do plaintext matching", this skips doing regex and makes it faster.
- grep `-q` silences output and quits once there is a single match, returning a `true` or `false` that you can chain with `&&`

After that the shell will continue running commands as usual.

The cool thing about this approach is that we can use it for anything, even to monitor a docker container until a string is found.

```sh
docker logs container_name -f | while read LINE; do echo ${LINE}; echo "${LINE}" | grep -Fq 'Listening on 0.0.0.0' && pkill -P $$; done; echo "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on the answer from Phio https://superuser.com/a/1052328/102262, I wrote this version on a function and that works both on Linux and MacOSX

```
wait_for_pattern() {
    local file="$1"
    local pattern="$2"
    # Two parts:
    # 1. tail follow the file in background, printing the PID and waiting for it
    # 2. add a trap to kill the tail PID on exit, read PID from first line, sed to match the first occurrence
    (
        (sleep 1; exec tail -n 1000 -f "${file}") & echo $! ; wait
    ) | (
        trap 'kill "$pid"' EXIT; pid="$(head -1)";
        sed -n "/${pattern}/{p;q;}"
    )
}

wait_for_pattern /tmp/foo Lib
```

Explanation:

1. starts a subprocess running in background
2. Subproccess sleep 1 to wait for the next piped process to read the pid
3. then execs into tail
4. print the PID of the background process
5. we add a wait to wait for tail in background to finish
6. The piped subprocess would setup a trap to kill the PID.
7. read the PID from first line
8. sed will match the pattern and exit on first occurrence. This sed syntax is compatible with macosx

Answer (score -2):

**how about this:**

while true; 
do 
if [ ! -z $(grep "myRegEx" myLog.log) ];
then break;
fi ;
done