# "watch" the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to programmatically watch the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit.  This is very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found) question, but instead of tailing a file, I want to 'tail' a command.

Something like:

```
watch -n1 my_cmd | grep -m 1 "String Im Looking For"
```

(But this doesn't work for me.)

**UPDATE:** I need to clarify that `my_cmd` does not continuously output text but needs to be repeatedly called until the string is found (which is why I thought of the `watch` command).  In this respect, `my_cmd` is like many other Unix commands such as: `ps`, `ls`, `lsof`, `last`, etc.

Comment: I would have thought it was possible to `tail -f` a program output just as well as a file... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Joanis.  You're right, but in my case 'my_cmd' doesn't continuously produce output and must be repeatedly called (much like most commands: ps, ls, lsof, etc)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
until my_cmd | grep -m 1 "String Im Looking For"; do : ; done
```

Instead of `:`, you can use `sleep 1` (or 0.2) to ease the CPU.

The loop runs until grep finds the string in the command's output. `-m 1` means "one match is enough", i.e. grep stops searching after it finds the first match.

You can also use `grep -q` which also quits after finding the first match, but without printing the matching line.

Comment: someone else mentioned `grep -q` which is another option. grep quits after finding the string.

Comment: note that this command will repeatedly run the command in question, which might or might not be desirable.

Comment: @A__: It's desirable, as stated in the OP under "Update".

Comment: I recommend inserting a sleep so the CPU is not overly taxed. Example: `until my_cmd | grep -q foo; do ; sleep 1; done; echo 'Found'`. Depending on the task you might want a much longer sleep period.

Comment: @KeithBennett: That's what I suggested on the third line.

Answer (score 17):

```
watch -e "! my_cmd | grep -m 1 \"String Im Looking For\""
```

- `!` negates the exit code of the command pipeline
- `grep -m 1` exits when string is found
- `watch -e` returns if any error has occured

But this can be improved to actually display that matched line, which is thrown away so far.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but it doesn't work for me.  My `watch` command (CentOS) doesn't have the `-e` flag (which shouldn't really matter).  More importantly, though, when the string is found, watch continues to run and does not exit.  It seems that when `grep -m` exits, it only exits kills `my_cmd`, but not `watch`.

Comment: Nope, is does matter!, the "-e" flag is ment for leaving watch when the command has an error code different from 0. Since its not present watch is about to continue on your platform. Anyhow, good to know, on my Ubuntu 11.10 installation everything is fine. I have also sometimes troubles with Mac OSX regarding very very outdated commandline tools and I am using mac ports so far to get more current software.

Comment: This stops if the pattern is found, but it doesn't show any output until that happens

Comment: You may employ `tee` for that, but this introduces a misleading newline, I don't know how to circumvent right now: `watch -n1 -e "! date | tee /dev/tty | grep --color -m 1 \"17\""`

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me. `watch` dutifully stops watching when the string is found, but it doesn't actually exit until you press a key. So close.

Comment: But using `-g` instead seems to do the trick!

Comment: I've tried various variations of this and can't get it to work. No matter what I do, even though the string is found in `stdout`, the command doesn't exit. Example: `watch -g "! docker run --tty --volume $(pwd)/test/jekyll-plantuml:/srv/jekyll --env DEBUG=true swedbankpay/jekyll-plantuml:1.3.5 | tee /dev/tty | grep -q \"Server running\""`

Answer (score 11):

For those who have a program that is continuously writing to stdout, all you need to do is pipe it to grep with the 'single match' option. Once grep finds the matching string, it will exit, which closes stdout on the process that is being piped to grep. This event *should* naturally cause the program to gracefully exit **so long as the process writes again**.

What will happen is that the process will receive a SIGPIPE when it tries writing to closed stdout after grep has exited. Here is an example with ping, which would otherwise run indefinitely:

```
$ ping superuser.com | grep -m 1 "icmp_seq"
```

This command will match the first successful 'pong', and then exit the next time `ping` tries writing to stdout.

---

**However,**

It's not always guaranteed that the process will write to stdout again and therefore might not cause a SIGPIPE to be raised (e.g., this can happen when tailing a log file). The best solution i've managed to come up with for this scenario involves writing to a file; please comment if you think you can improve:

```
$ { tail -f log_file & echo $! > pid; } | { grep -m1 "find_me" && kill -9 $(cat pid) && rm pid; }
```

Breaking this down:

1. `tail -f log_file & echo $! > pid` - tails a file, attaches process to background, and saves the PID (`$!`) to a file. I tried exporting the PID to a variable instead, but it seems there's a race condition between here and when the PID is used again.
2. `{  ...  ;}` - [group](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) these commands together so we can pipe the output to grep while keeping the current context (helps when saving and reusing variables, but wasn't able to get that part working)
3. `|` - pipe left side's stdout to right side's stdin
4. `grep -m1 "find_me"` - find the target string
5. `&& kill -9 $(cat pid)` - force kill (SIGKILL) the `tail` process **after** `grep` exits once it finds the matching string
6. `&& rm pid` - remove the file we created

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: `{ docker run --tty --volume $(pwd)/test/jekyll-plantuml:/srv/jekyll --env DEBUG=true swedbankpay/jekyll-plantuml:1.3.5 & echo $! > pid; } | { grep -m1 "Server running" && kill -9 $(cat pid) && rm pid; }`

Comment: Also, if you'd like to read the entire output from the first command and not just what's matched by `grep`, you can inject the following between `}` and `{`: `} | tee /dev/tty | {`. If `tty` is not available (on a build server, for instance), replace `/dev/tty` with `/dev/stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

To watch the output without modifying it, and with a timeout there can be used a "waitforoutput" micro Python application.

```
pip install waitforoutput
waitforoutput 'String Im Looking For' --command 'watch my_cmd' --timeout 10
```

On the official README there is more detailed explanation on the behavior: https://pypi.org/project/waitforoutput/

Comment: This may solve the problem– but this is no 'micro python' application if it installs 28 other package dependancies.

For those who want to undo isntalling this either `pip uninstall waitforoutput Pygments SecretStorage attrs bleach cffi colorama cryptography docutils jeepney jsonschema keyring packaging pbr pycparser pyparsing pyrsistent requests rfc3986 rkd rkd tabulate tqdm twine typing waitforoutput webencodings readme-renderer python-dotenv importlib-metadata` or install _another_ package `pip install pip-autoremove` and `pip-autoremove waitforoutput` to safely remove this.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_cmd | tail +1f | sed '/String Im Looking For/q'
```

If `tail` doesn't support the `+1f` syntax, try `tail -f -n +1`.  (The `-n +1` tells it to start at the beginning; `tail -f` by default starts with the last 10 lines of output.)

Comment: Please see my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Append the result of your program calls to a file. Then `tail -f` that file. That way it should work... I hope.

When you restart calling that program you'll have to erase the file or append some gibberish to it just so it doesn't match again right away what you were looking for.