# Integrating "watch" with "top" logging until finished - HOW?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, top, watch

I stumbled across this link: ["watch" the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit](https://superuser.com/questions/375223/watch-the-output-of-a-command-until-a-particular-string-is-observed-and-then-e)

I know the PID of the process.  I want to log the process "resource-consumption" using top.

Basically `top -p PID -b >> LOGFILE`.

I want to have this run in increments, say every 5 seconds using the "watch" command

```
watch -n 5
```

From an independent/external program, I will append "We Are Finished" to the logfile.

I want the logging of watch/top to break/exit when "We are Finished"  So `grep` should be evaluating the entire log file, not just the current value.

I want the command to run in a nonblocking form... maybe ends with " `&` "

I set -d to 5 so top and watch are creating at the same time?
...

Here is my attempt using the "-e" option suggested from the link above, not working as expected...  PID and LOGFILE are appropriate values.

```
watch -n 5 -e "!  top -d 5 -b -p PID >> LOGFILE | grep -m 1 \"We Are Finished\"" &
```

Comment: If you append standard output to `LOGFILE`, then nothing is piped to `grep`. You need to pipe through `tee -a LOGFILE` to direct output to both places, or (more complex) make `grep` take its input from `LOGFILE` after it has been written.

Comment: @afh thanks for the ideas... can you provide the tee syntax?  I do not need "more complex" since "We are Finished" is not being written by this watch loop.

Comment: watch -n 5 -e "!  top -d 5 -b -p PID >> LOGFILE | grep -m 1 \"We Are Finished\" LOGFILE "  &

Comment: I don't understand your comments: you have just reiterated your original command with an erroneous extra double-quote. I gave you the syntax in my comment above: replace `>> LOGFILE` with `| tee -a LOGFILE`, but if `"We are Finished"` is not being written why are you looking for it?

Comment: @AFH "We are Finished" is being written by an external program... The external program executes this "logging" feature.... and the logging feature stops itself on "We are Finished"

Comment: This is why I added "LOGFILE" twice.  once on the grep side...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it on the end. You should use `&&` instead of `|` before `grep`. The reason I said this was more complex is that `"We are Finished"` may be in `LOGFILE` before the command is run, whereas `tee` detects the string in each run of the command only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
until grep -qm 1 '\"We Are Finished\"' LOGFILE; do top -d 5 -n 12 -b -p PID >> LOGFILE; done
```

---

If you want to exit the logging on a process when the pid is no longer running the script below should work? (this avoids two processes writing to same file?)

It takes three parameters: the PID, the location of LOGFILE and the TIME between log entries.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
  then
    echo "Usage logpid (PID) (LOGFILE) (Time between in sec)"
    exit 1;
fi

while :
    do 
    if  ps -p $1 > /dev/null ; then
    top -n 1 -b -p $1 >> $2;
    else
    echo "Exited No pid";
    break;
    fi
    sleep $3;   
done
```