# running for loop - but wait for string of words in log file to continue

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

so far I have this:

```
for each in {01..10} ; do ./sb0$each/tomcat_sb0$each start;done
```

that will start my apps at once, but I want it to wait until it reads one line in a file, what's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ! grep "the line you're searching for" /path/to/the.file
do sleep 10; done
for each in {01..10} ; do ./sb0$each/tomcat_sb0$each start;done
```

This solution has a `while` loop that will continue as long as the line you're searching for isn't found in the file. The loop contains just a `sleep` of 10 seconds, so that it will check every ten seconds for the line you want. Obviously you could set this to whatever you want.

The `grep` searches for a pattern in a given file, and returns false if nothing matches the pattern. The `!` means not, and as not false = true, the loop continues as long as the `grep` command returns false.

For example, if you're looking for the line **start the apps now chuck** in file **/var/tmp/foo.txt** it would look like

```
 while ! grep "start the apps now chuck" /var/tmp/foo.txt;
```

If the line exists the answer won't have zero length so the conditional will return false and the loop will exit.

Comment: I would suggest using 'while ! grep "start the apps now chuck" /var/tmp/foo.txt' instead.  Fewer moving parts.  (the exit code for grep indicates whether the string was found)