# Using bash to read FFmpeg terminal output

Tags: bash, video, terminal, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a little question how to read output text from terminal, generated by FFmpeg when running. I have a streaming server with a camera stream, which sometimes corrupts and drops, when there are internet connection issues in the location camera is placed at. This stream is checked by the `while` loop and when the connection drops completely, loop tries to restart it.

But in some occasions, when there is some huge packet loss, stream corrupts, but does not stop completely. FFmpeg encoding hangs and the connection to server does not drop. (My "restart" loop is useless then). When this occurs, FPS of video starts to drop to lower values and then I need to capture that value and make required actions.

That line with that info looks like this:

> ```
> frame=74190 fps= 20 q=0.0 size=  285208kB time=01:01:49.45 bitrate= 629.9kbits/s
> ```

So if the value in `fps= 20` drops to 18 and lower, appropriate actions are made. What do I need to use? I tried piping to `grep` but without any success.

I will be happy for any solutions or tips to make any progress.

Answer (score 4):

Note that ffmpeg's output is written to `stderr` and not `stdout` ([what is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr)).

If you want to `grep` ffmpeg's log output, you need to first pipe everything from `stderr` to `stdout`, which in Bash you can do with:

```
ffmpeg … 2>&1 | grep …
```

If you are running processes from a server, it would however be better to direct the output to a log file instead, then `grep` this if you need to.

```
ffmpeg … 2>&1 > /var/log/ffmpeg.log
grep "fps=…" /var/log/ffmpeg.log
```

Note that with every new call of `> /var/log/ffmpeg.log`, that particular file is truncated and rewritten by your shell. You can append to an existing file by using `>>` instead.

Comment: To monitor the logfile on the fly one can use [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/900134/432690) (I'm linking to the answer that appears the best to me).